# How to patch form array in typed angular reactive forms

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, strong-typing

I am trying to figure out how to patch form array in a typed reactive Angular form.  patchValue and setValue does not work in my mind consistently with FormControl for example.
Here is a form

```js
 this.form = fb.group<IPersonForm>({
      name: new FormControl<string | null>('bob'),
      phones: new FormArray<FormGroup<IPhoneForm>>([]),
    });
```

I can patch name control easily enough:

```js
this.form.controls.name.patchValue('Jim', { onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false });
```

But form array is a challenge.  Say I create a replacemenmt array

```js
const myPhone = this.fb.group<IPhoneForm>({
      phone: new FormControl<string | null | undefined>('bob')
    });
const array = new FormArray<FormGroup<IPhoneForm>>([myPhone]);
```

Now if I try to patch (or set), neither compiles:

```js
    //this.form.controls.phones.setValue(array);
    //this.form.controls.phones.setValue(array.controls);
    //this.form.controls.phones.patchValue(array);
    //this.form.controls.phones.patchValue(array.controls);
```

I can use setControl, but that method does not have an option for onlySelf:

```js
this.form.setControl('phones', array, { emitEvent: false });
```

I feel like onlySelf is needed there because if I am replacing the data and have complex validations, I do not want them to run on any control until entire form is patched.
Thank you!

Here is a stackblitz with a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-path-typed-array?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should pass the logical value, not another form to the patch

```
this.form.controls.phones.patchValue([{phone: '123'}]);
```

or

```
this.form.patchValue({phones: [{phone: '123'}]})
```

also possible to do in one call with the name at the same time

```
this.form.patchValue({name: 'Jim', phones: [{phone: '123'}]})
```

you can add onlySelf or emitEvent if you want. they are both unrelated to the question.

Comment: Thank  you!  I mentioned onlySelf because the bigger problem I am trying to solve is to patch FormArray with number of entries larger than what exists there at the moment.  patchValue will blow up.  If I fire push, that method does not have an onlySelf option, therefore will run the rules on the entire form before the entire form is patched fully with new array items.  I guess I will submit an enhancement request to Angular team for that.  Thanks again!

Comment: Opened this issue on GitHub https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/53042

Answer (score 1):

When you patch an formArray, If the formArray have not enough elements this elements are not added. If less element, only the first elements are changed.

e.g.

```
  formArray=new FormArray<FormGroup<IPhoneForm>>([this.newPhoneGroup()])
  ngOnInit(){
    const dataArray=[{phone:'222222'},{phone:'33333'}]
    this.formArray.patchValue(dataArray)
  }
  newPhoneGroup()
  {
    return new FormGroup({
      phone:new FormControl()
    })
  }
```

your formArrayElement only have **only one** element!

You need

```
    dataArray=[{phone:'222222'},{phone:'33333'}]

    this.formArray.clear();
    while (this.formArray.controls.length<dataArray.length)
      this.formArray.push(this.newPhoneGroup());

    
    this.formArray.patchValue(dataArray)
```

You can also take another aproach:

Change the function newPhoneGroup like

```
  newPhoneGroup(data:any=null)
  {
    data=data || {phone:''}
    return new FormGroup({
      phone:new FormControl(data.phone)
    })
  }
```

And write

```
  this.formArray=dataArray.map(x=>this.newFormGroup(x))
```

Comment: Yes, correct.  This works,  The only challenge is that the rules will run every time you "push" into the array, even though not full data is in the reactive form yet.  Therefore I think Angular is missing a feature to pass onlySelf to the push for this approach to work the same way as patch entire form.